# RESTful request with advanced filter (1-N-1 relationship)

Tags: rest, restful-url

I have 3 different resources :

```
/articles
/reviews
/reviewers
```

As a database design, we would have :

```
+----------+
| Articles |
+----------+
| id       |
| title    |
| content  |
+----------+

+-------------+
|   Reviews   |
+-------------+
| id          |
| id_article  |
| id_reviewer |
| content     |
+-------------+

+-----------+
| Reviewers |
+-----------+
| id        |
| name      |
+-----------+
```

Is there a RESTful way to fetch all the articles which were reviewed by the reviewer whose name is 'Jack' ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

By modelling your resources according to the use case. In this case, you'll want a resource that returns specifically all the articles reviewed by Jack, and not find a combination of the other resources to come to your answer.

Your resources should closely match the problem you're trying to solve, and the database schema is irrelevant. In this case, I could envision there exists a resource that returns all the articles that allows you to specify the name of the user that reviewed the articles, like so:

`GET /articles?reviewed-by=Jack`

The response could contain articles, and perhaps some information about the reviews themselves if your use case requires this.

Comment: You had me at "the database schema is irrelevant". :)